# Varying amplitude of beats

Tags: waves, oscillators, superposition, vibrations, harmonics

[image]
Why is the product of 2X and cosine delta t divided by 2 is the varying amplitude and not the other 2X and cosine function?

Answer (score 1):

The cosine function varies between $\pm 1$ and you are multiplying two such cosine functions together.
I have used $\omega =5$ and $\delta =0.1$ to draw the graphs all with amplitude one.

[image]

You are quite right in that you can tag the $2A$ to either of the cosine functions:

- it is a high frequency cosine function of amplitude one whose
  amplitude is modulated by a  low frequency cosine of amplitude $2A$
- it is a high frequency cosine function of amplitude $2A$ whose
  amplitude is modulated by a  low frequency cosine of amplitude one
- it is a high frequency cosine function of amplitude $A$ whose
  amplitude is modulated by a low frequency cosine of amplitude two

If the two wave frequencies were the same $\omega = 5$ with each with amplitude $A$ then you would get a constant amplitude wave of $2A$.

The first variant is the one which is most commonly used as it is possibly easier to state and understand?

- it is a high frequency note whose amplitude is modulated by a lower
  frequency cosine function

or

- it is high frequency note with a fixed amplitude whose amplitude is
  modulated by a lower frequency cosine function.

Comment: Can that function be considered a simple harmonic motion?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz The "beats" graph ($y$ vs $t$) shows you the displacement of a particle at a fixed mean position as a function of time. The motion of the particle is certainly harmonic in that the motion repeats itself with time but as the amplitude of the motion is not constant it cannot be called simple harmonic motion.